# Duvida em string, e comparação

Tags: c, string

Estou com dúvida no seguinte exercício:

> Escreva um programa em C que receba duas strings via entrada padrão e
> informe se a segunda string está contida na primeira, ou seja, se a
> segunda string é um segmento da primeira. Você pode considerar, em seu
> programa, que a segunda string é sempre menor que a primeira, e que as
> strings possuem, no máximo, 100 caracteres. Segue um exemplo de
> entrada e saída. O que está sublinhado foi fornecido pelo usuário.
>
> - String 1: programa
> - String 2: grama
>
> A segunda string esta contida na primeira!

O código que eu fiz, sempre fala a que "A segunda string está contida na primeira".
Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
    
    char string1[101];
    char string2[101];
    int i, x;
    
    printf("Forneca a string 1:  \n");
    scanf("%s",string1);
    printf("Forneca a string 2:  \n");
    scanf("%s",string2);
    
    x=strlen(string2);
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        if(string2[i]=string1[i]){
            printf("A segunda string esta contida na primeira. \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que não esta dando certo?

Comment: a) `=` seria `==`; b) `scanf("%s",string1)` só lê uma palavra (termina no primeiro espaço...

Answer (score 2):

O operador `=`, em C, não é uma comparação, é uma atribuição. No trecho que você faz:

```
string2[i]=string1[i]
```

Você está sobrescrevendo o i-nésimo caractere da `string2`. E sim, dentro de um `if` uma atribuição é verdadeira, então o que tá dentro do `if` é executado.

Para comparar, utilize `==`.

Outra coisa, você precisa mudar seu algoritmo. Ele vai dizer que uma string está dentro da outra sempre que os caracteres na mesma posição forem iguais.

Ao invés disso, faça assim:

- Corra todos os caracteres da string maior, até encontrar um que seja igual ao primeiro caractere da string menor.
- A partir daí, se os N-1 próximos caracteres da string maior (onde N é o tamanho da string menor) forem iguais aos N-1 próximos caracteres da menor, a menor está contida na maior.
- Se o passo acima não for conclusivo, continue procurando outro caractere na string maior que seja igual ao primeiro caractere da string menor e repita o segundo passo.
- Se chegou ao (M - N)-ésimo (onde M é o tamanho da string maior, e N o tamanho da menor) caractere da string maior e não encontrou a string menor dentro dela, a string menor não está contida na string maior.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A funcao `strstr()` da biblioteca padrão verifica se uma string esta contida na outra, não há necessidade de reinventar a roda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];

    printf("Forneca a primeira string: ");
    fgets( str1, sizeof(str1), stdin );
    str1[ strcspn(str1, "\n") ] = 0;

    printf("Forneca a segunda string: ");
    fgets( str2, sizeof(str2), stdin );
    str2[ strcspn(str2, "\n") ] = 0;

    if( strstr( str1, str2 ) )
        printf("A segunda string esta contida na primeira!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, no meio acadêmico, o desafio é entender como a `strstr()` funciona por baixo dos panos, segue uma segunda implementação sem usar a função citada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


const char * minha_strstr( const char * palheiro, const char * agulha )
{
    do {
        const char * p = palheiro;
        const char * a = agulha;

        while( (*p == *a) && (*a) )
        {
            a++;
            p++;
        }

        if( *a == 0 )
            return palheiro;

    } while (*palheiro++);

    return NULL;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];

    printf("Forneca a primeira string: ");
    fgets( str1, sizeof(str1), stdin );
    str1[ strcspn(str1, "\n") ] = 0;

    printf("Forneca a segunda string: ");
    fgets( str2, sizeof(str2), stdin );
    str2[ strcspn(str2, "\n") ] = 0;

    if( minha_strstr( str1, str2 ) )
        printf("A segunda string esta contida na primeira!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!